# Error en hclust al generar un heatmap en R con valores NA/NaN/Inf

Tags: r, dataframe, cluster

Estoy intentando generar un heatmap en R utilizando la función `pheatmap`. Tengo un conjunto de datos en formato df con múltiples columnas y algunas filas contienen valores NA. Al ejecutar el código, recibo el siguiente error:

```
Error in hclust(d, method = method) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf en llamada a una función externa (arg 10)
```

He intentado reemplazar los valores NA con `df[is.na(df)] <-0` , sustituyendo en 0 o con otra constante pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error.

Aquí está mi código:

```r
pheatmap(hm, scale="row",
         clustering_method = "complete", cluster_rows = TRUE, cluster_cols = FALSE,
         clustering_distance_rows = "correlation",
         show_rownames = FALSE,
         cellheight = NA, cellwidth = NA,
         color=colorRampPalette(c("royalblue1", "white", "firebrick2"))(100),
         fontsize_row = 1, angle_col = 0, fontsize_for_colnames = 10)
```

Al cambiar `cluster_rows = FALSE` permite ejecutar el código pero necesito que agrupe por filas.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a entender por qué estoy recibiendo este error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

¿Sería posible mantener los valores NA y asignarles un color específico para distinguirlos visualmente? Probé con `na_col` pero sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

La estructura de datos sería:

```
'data.frame':   2524 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ Genes: chr  "protein1" "protein2" "protein3" "protein4" "protein5" ...
 $ 1-1  : num  4288 NA 1254 11802 NA ...
 $ 2-1  : num  NA NA NA 6757 NA ...
 $ 3-1  : num  2381 NA NA 13049 NA ...
 $ 1-2  : num  3863 NA 4661 16570 NA ...
 $ 2-2  : num  13721 2273 5995 28510 NA ...
 $ 3-2  : num  7398 NA 3226 23144 NA ...
 $ 1-3  : num  NA NA NA 14077 NA ...
 $ 2-3  : num  8400 NA 4779 22975 11769 ...
 $ 3-3  : num  6061 3618 3267 18303 NA ...
 $ 1-4  : num  6030 NA 10520 20567 NA ...
 $ 2-4  : num  5058 3783 3636 16005 6359 ...
 $ 3-4  : num  3849 518 3243 14334 NA ...
```

¡Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda que puedan proporcionar!

---

ACTUALIZACIÓN 27.02.24:
Si pruebo con el ejemplo proporcionado en la respuesta pero con otros valores, el error persiste:

```
hm <- data.frame(
  Genes = c("protein1", "protein2", "protein3", "protein4", "protein5"),
  `1-1` = c(852.3800, 6278.5300, NA, 283.8990, NA),
  `2-1` = c(396.971, 3153.150, NA, NA, NA),
  `3-1` = c(1155.600, 8001.870, NA, NA, NA),
  `1-2` = c(NA, 4849.230, 870.429, 271.163, NA),
  `2-2` = c(NA, 2644.320, NA, NA, NA),
  check.names = FALSE
)

# Convertimos la columna 1 en un rowname
rownames(hm) <- hm$Genes
hm <- hm[-1]

hm
```

```
pheatmap(hm, 
         scale="row",
         clustering_method = "complete", 
         cluster_rows = TRUE, 
         cluster_cols = FALSE,
         clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean",
         show_rownames = T,
         cellheight = NA, cellwidth = NA,
         color=colorRampPalette(c("royalblue1", "white", "firebrick2"))(100),
         fontsize_row = 1, angle_col = 0, fontsize_for_colnames = 10)
```

```
Error in hclust(d, method = method) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf en llamada a una función externa (arg 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema más importante es que `pheatmap()`  espera una matriz numérica, y lo que le está pasando es un `data.frame` que no puede convertirse en una matriz numérica, por la columna 1. Por lo que la primer medida sería eliminar esta o mejor aún convertirla en un `rowname`:

```
hm <- data.frame(
  Genes = c("protein1", "protein2", "protein3", "protein4", "protein5"),
  `1-1` = c(4288, NA, 1254, 11802, NA),
  `2-1` = c(NA, NA, NA, 6757, NA),
  `3-1` = c(2381, NA, NA, 13049, NA),
  `1-2` = c(3863, NA, 4661, 16570, NA),
  `2-2` = c(13721, 2273, 5995, 28510, NA),
  `3-2` = c(7398, NA, 3226, 23144, NA),
  `1-3` = c(NA, NA, NA, 14077, NA),
  `2-3` = c(8400, NA, 4779, 22975, 11769),
  `3-3` = c(6061, 3618, 3267, 18303, NA),
  `1-4` = c(6030, NA, 10520, 20567, NA),
  `2-4` = c(5058, 3783, 3636, 16005, 6359),
  `3-4` = c(3849, 518, 3243, 14334, NA), 
  check.names = FALSE
)

# Convertimos la columna 1 en un rowname
rownames(hm) <- hm$Genes
hm <- hm[-1]

hm

           1-1  2-1   3-1   1-2   2-2   3-2   1-3   2-3   3-3   1-4   2-4   3-4
protein1  4288   NA  2381  3863 13721  7398    NA  8400  6061  6030  5058  3849
protein2    NA   NA    NA    NA  2273    NA    NA    NA  3618    NA  3783   518
protein3  1254   NA    NA  4661  5995  3226    NA  4779  3267 10520  3636  3243
protein4 11802 6757 13049 16570 28510 23144 14077 22975 18303 20567 16005 14334
protein5    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 11769    NA    NA  6359    NA
```

Con esto ya podrías generar el mapa salvo por un detalle, estás usando `clustering_distance_rows = "correlation"` lo cual exige que no haya `NAs` ya que internamente se calcula la matriz de distancias de esta forma:

```
as.dist(1 - cor(t(hm)))
```

Dando como resultado un matriz inválida para lo que sigue:

```
         protein1 protein2 protein3 protein4
protein2       NA                           
protein3       NA       NA                  
protein4       NA       NA       NA         
protein5       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Acá tienes dos alternativas, en mi opinión, la más adecuada sería dejar los `NA` y usar otro tipo de calculo de distancia, por ejemplo `euclidean`:

```
pheatmap(hm, 
         scale="row",
         clustering_method = "complete", 
         cluster_rows = TRUE, 
         cluster_cols = FALSE,
         clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean",
         show_rownames = FALSE,
         cellheight = NA, cellwidth = NA,
         color=colorRampPalette(c("royalblue1", "white", "firebrick2"))(100),
         fontsize_row = 1, angle_col = 0, fontsize_for_colnames = 10)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La otra opción es lo que intentaste, imputar los `NA` pero a mi criterio, esto genera una distancia ficticia.

```
hm[is.na(hm)] <-0
pheatmap(hm, 
         scale="row",
         clustering_method = "complete", 
         cluster_rows = TRUE, 
         cluster_cols = FALSE,
         clustering_distance_rows = "correlation",
         show_rownames = FALSE,
         cellheight = NA, cellwidth = NA,
         color=colorRampPalette(c("royalblue1", "white", "firebrick2"))(100),
         fontsize_row = 1, angle_col = 0, fontsize_for_colnames = 10)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias. Puedo reproducir su código, pero al aplicarlo a mis datos sigue el  Error in hclust(d, method = method): NA/NaN/Inf en llamada a una función externa (arg 10) 3. hclust(d, method = method) 2. cluster_mat(mat, distance = clustering_distance_rows, method = clustering_method) 1. pheatmap(hm, scale = "row", clustering_method = "complete", cluster_rows = TRUE, cluster_cols = FALSE, clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean", show_rownames = FALSE, cellheight = NA, cellwidth = NA, color = colorRampPalette(c("royalblue1", "white", "firebrick2"))(100), fontsize_row = 1, angle_col = 0, ...

Comment: Obviamente sin poder ver los datos es difícil ayudarte, lo que te puedo decir es que el error inicial se debía a que partías de una matriz no numérica, revisa esto, incluso intenta convertir el data.frame en una matriz y revisa que esta  sea numérica, por ese lado seguramente viene el tema.

Comment: Probé a convertir en matriz y comprobar que es numérica pero el error persiste. ¿Podría deberse a valores específicos de mi dataframe? Si pruebo a crear otro df pero con otros de mis valores aparece de nuevo el error (edito la pregunta con la nueva prueba)

Comment: Claro, ¿hay información suficiente y de calidad para construir la matriz de distancias? Ciertamente tener múltiples valores NA no ayuda para esto. Pero no puedo decirte mucho, en el ejemplo que diste, la explicación es claramente  de problema es la respuesta que te dí, ahora evidentemente trabajas con un set de datos distinto al de tu pregunta, por lo que la solución  no necesariamente explica tu nuevo problema, el tema es que no tengo forma de ayudarte sin ver al menos los datos reales con los que estás trabajando.